# how to add an activity to the android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

How do I add:

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity2"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
</activity>
```

into the AndroidManifest.xml

which currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bac"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I'm fairly new to android programming and have yet to figure out a lot of stuff about transferring between pages and other things like that. Thanks for any help you give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Add another `Activity tag` under your `application tag`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bac"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity2"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

---

- If you are new to android and trying to understand about manifest
  Have a look at [ANDROID-DEVELOPERS-SITE ..... Click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)
- Have a look at [youtube-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwJwX6wMTxQ&noredirect=1) too hope this helps

---

It has all the information you need to get started knowing more about the manifest file

Comment: @ SilentKiller .... Yes, bigger sign was not required .... Re-edited ... thanks for pointing it !

Comment: It still there. even boldness too not required.

Answer (score 0):

you can add any number of `activity` inside your `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bac"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <!-- activity goes here-->
         <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity2"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
         </activity>

    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `Activity` inside `Application` tag.

The activity is the child node of the application node. The multiple activities can specify by multiple nodes of activity.

[*Read this : manifest-intro*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

your manifest will be look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bac"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Add your activities here -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

to add an activity to the Manifest , just copy the content of the exesting activity in the manifest and remove the intent filter like this 
---the original

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---the new

```
<activity
        android:name=".yourNewActivityName"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


    </activity>
```

you need add this in the application tag.

you need to change the android:name property to your new activity's name